# After upgrading to Rails 4.1, new polymorphic associations are invalid when saving them along with their parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

After upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4.1, the following code which used to work is now failing:

in a controller/spec:

```
post = user.posts.build
post.contacts << contact # contact is a persisted record
post.save! # now fails
```

I'm basically trying to save the post along with its associated contact, which is supposed to create a `contact_publishment` record on-the-fly. 
The error is on the new `contact_publishment` record: **"Publishable can't be blank"**

the model:

```
class Contact
  ...
  has_many :contact_publishments
  ...
end

class ContactPublishment
  ...
  belongs_to :publishable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :contact
  validates_uniqueness_of :publishable_id, :scope => [:contact_id, :publishable_type]
  validates_presence_of :contact, :publishable
  ...
end

class Post
  ...
  has_many :contact_publishments, as: :publishable
  has_many :contacts, through: :contact_publishments
  ...
end
```

Comment: You get the error on the `save!` or on the `<<` line?

Comment: Would be helpful to see your validations

Comment: ok. i'll edit them in. but the point is that this code woked perfectly on Rails 3.2, and the update screwed it up. moreover, with similar, non-polymorphic relations i dont get these issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Rails 3.2 owner model has been saved before perform validation nested association, in 4.1 validation before model saved, and because post not saved, validation

```
class ContactPublishment
    validates_presence_of :publishable
```

does not allow to pass validation (post not saved in db)

For resolve this, you may disable validation in Post model, (validation on  ContactPublishment has been called from Contact model)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :contact_publishments, as: :publishable, validate: false
```

or replace presence validation like this:

```
class ContactPublishment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_associated :publishable

change_column :contact_publishments, :publishable_type, :string, null: false
change_column :contact_publishments, :publishable_id, :integer, null: false
```

or do it through proxy_association

Comment: Thank you! it worked! except for the `change_table` commands, which i had to change to `change_column`. Big thank you, i was stuck on this for a few days.

Comment: Of course, it would be correct change_column, when he wrote, thought about  ALTER TABLE. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, this is a really strange thing for them to change in Rails... :P

Answer (score 1):

I think the association is not updating because you do not have `inverse_of` setup between  contact and contact_publishment.

[From the docs about setting up a :through](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)

> If you are going to modify the association (rather than just read from
>   it), then it is a good idea to set the :inverse_of option on the
>   source association on the join model. This allows associated records
>   to be built which will automatically create the appropriate join model
>   records when they are saved.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. Regardless, the problem is not with the `contact`, but with the `contact_publishment` and the `post`. Moreover, `inverse_of` doesn't work with polymorphic associations so it will not work in the case of the `post`